# Output specific dates

Tags: r, xts

I am having difficulty using `xts`.  Either only a header is output or all values are output when I use the following (or with alterations to the date).

```
datax1["14/04/2014"]
```

I am reading in a data in the following format using `read.csv`

```
Date     Time   ws  wd
1 10/04/14 00:00:00 1.88 118
2 10/04/14 00:04:30 1.91 118
3 10/04/14 00:09:00 1.90 114
```

Then, I use the following to convert Date and Time columns to date and time.

```
datax1 <- xts(data1[-c(1,2)],
as.POSIXlt(paste(as.Date(data1$Date, format="%d-%m-%y"),
data1$Time), tz=""))
```

After this stage, when I run the  commmand to output data from a specific date, only a header or all data from all dates is output.  Any help appreciated on how to get this to work.

Edited to add - the full range of data extends from 10/04/14 - 29/04/14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the error is the format string passed to `as.Date`.  It specifies `-` characters, but you're using `/` characters in the actual input.

The easiest way to do the desired operation, is to use `paste` on the columns themselves, then pass to `as.POSIXlt` with an appropriate format string:

```
with(data1, as.POSIXlt(paste(Date, Time), format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"))
## [1] "2014-04-10 00:00:00" "2014-04-10 00:04:30" "2014-04-10 00:09:00"
```